# getPropertyValue() includes whitespace of CSS formating when retrieving Custom CSS Property Values

Tags: javascript, css, dom, custom-properties

When I get the value of a custom CSS property, the `getPropertyValue` method returns a DOMString that includes the whitespace I used in my [CSS formatting](http://www.lonniebest.com/FormatCSS/). Is there a different method that I should be using to obtain the value of custom CSS properties (one that doesn't require trimming afterwards)?

```js
function getCustomPropertyValue(element,customPropertyName)
{
    let style = window.getComputedStyle(element);
    return style.getPropertyValue(customPropertyName);
}
let value = getCustomPropertyValue(document.body,"--color1");
console.log(`'${value}'`);
```

```css
body { --color1: #333333; }
```

Notice that, when you run the code snippet, the `getPropertyValue` function returns a value having a leading whitespace (that is an artifact of my CSS formatting).

Comment: if you write your css like this `body { --color1:#333333; }` then its gone. kinda funny. i would trim your return value

Comment: I noticed that too and do intend to trim if `getPropertyValue` is indeed the proper way to acquire custom CSS property values.

Comment: These days, the code above is returning `'#333333'` instead of `' #333333'`. I guess the whitespace was a bug, or ultimately decided against in the spec.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a deliberate decision to allow custom CSS properties to consider whitespace significant. So trimming is the way to go.

I have heard that registering the property with a defined syntax may change that, but I don't think it's standard yet nor have I tried it myself.

Comment: Was this deliberate decision changed? I'm not seeing that whitespace in 2024.

Comment: I don't really keep up on this, but I remember there being a decision a few of years ago that trimming whitespace would be better in principle. But there were also all sorts of edge cases to deal with. I guess we're finally at the point where that's been hashed out and we're started to see this be realized in browsers ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 1):

Just remove white-space in the CSS.

```
body { 
--color1:#333333; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It works when you use CSS variables the right way. You can find more details [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties).

```js
function getCustomPropertyValue(element, customPropertyName) {
  let style = window.getComputedStyle(element);
  return style.getPropertyValue(customPropertyName);
}
let value = getCustomPropertyValue(document.body, "--color1");
console.log(`'${value}'`);
```

```css
:root {
  --color1:#333333;
}

body {
  color: var(--color1);
}
```

Comment: When I run your code snippet, I see the [vary same leading space](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TyM6Q.png) that's outputted by mine. Getting the value from a descendant element, instead of the one where the custom value was created is not something I'd call "the right way". I can think of circumstances where the value can be different based on the element you ask and the right way is completely circumstantial.

Comment: @LonnieBest and the leading space is gone. Almost like a card trick.

Comment: You cheated! You changed `--color1: #333333;` to `--color1:#333333;` (removing that space from the CSS itself). You can't trick a [card trick programmer](http://www.lonniebest.com/CardTrick/), buddy! It's all good though. Enjoyed it. I up-voted you anyway.

Comment: auto formatters like prettier always adds this space